# How to document a complex set of interdependent controls for a web app?

Tags: documentation, dependencies, dependency-management

I've got a web app reporting interface with a dozen controls with multiple interdependencies, such as:

- if more than one campaign or "All" is selected for campaigns then Campaign should be in the Group By filter
- if it's the Product X view and the Secondary Publisher option has been assigned for this client, add the "Include Secondary Publisher" checkbox.
- if "Include Secondary Publisher" is checked, then add Secondary Publisher to the Group By filter

There are probably close to a hundred such rules and my code has gotten fairly complex. Before I undertake a big re-write, I want to document the dependencies so we can get some better automated tests in place.

Any pointers toward best practices for such documentation?

While I'm here, any pointers for managing the code complexity? (I'm thinking of using knockout.js, since it seems more or less built for this sort of situation....)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the right answer, but: go and write those automated tests themselves. They will act as executable documentation. If you write them with the same style and keep them short, they can be even human-readable, to some extent.

Comment: Shouldn't the QA team be writing the tests[1]? That's part of why I'm looking for a good way to document this -- to be able to communicate it to them.... [1] http://stackoverflow.com/q/295642/24197

Comment: Hm. I somehow don't agree with QA department doing this. If you go this path, then there should be QA employee writing the tests with you in a pair. Documents for the QA department? For me, ridiculous. But I don't know your company culture and size.